# How to parse string to call array and its array contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, expression

I want to parse string and call array using `valueForKeyPath:`

ex:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
```

I have a string's as below

```
myArray[], myArray[3],myArray[1..3]
```

when i evaluate these strings i want output like below

```
evaluate(@"myArray[]")
output:@[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
evaluate(@"myArray[3]")
output:4
evaluate(@"myArray[1..3]")
output:@[2,3,4]
```

I am already using custom function using `valueForKeyPath:` for calling methods and functions. I am stuck with array and parameters

Comment: It seems you're writing a small compiler.

Comment: Nope. my requirement is, i will get these string from server and i have to dynamically evaluate these strings from my app data and return the output to server.

Comment: That's what I mean.  You're taking text representations of expressions and attempting to execute them as code, which is a compiler-type function.  (Or maybe "interpreter" would be more accurate.)

Comment: Yup. You are correct. Do we have any way to do with NSExpression / Parsing via Regular Expression? which way is best to achieve?

Comment: Guys who downvoted, can you please update why?

Comment: Not me.  I'm still thinking about it.  (So far, I think you need a more dynamic language.  Perl would work.  :) )

Comment: But i want to implement in iOS application. Thanks for giving your inputs

Answer (score 1):

You have shown nothing you have attempted, so it is unclear what your problem is – you appear to know about things (`valueForKeyPath:`, regular expressions) you could build a solution from.

Here is an outline of a solution:

1. Your strings all appear to be of one of three forms: an array name followed by zero, one or two integers in square brackets. You can break this up to extract the one to three important parts using (at least) [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/) or [`NSScanner`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/). If you pick `NSRegularExpression` just be careful writing the pattern as `[`, `]`, and `.` are special characters and will need appropriate escaping – just read the documentation.
2. Once you have your three parts you can obtain the value of the array using `valueForKey:` assuming it is either a property or an instance variable.
3. If you have matched/scanned one or two indexes then you can use the methods of [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/) to obtain the object(s), you might find [`NSIndexSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSIndexSet/indexSetWithIndexesInRange:) useful here.

That's it. If you try to do this and get stuck edit your question showing what you have tried, state what is broken, and ask for help; someone will probably be able to help further.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, i will check this out